# Debugging React setState error

Tags: reactjs, debugging, setstate

I am not obviously setting state in any of my components constructors or the like yet i am getting the

`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component`

error. Is there any good way to debug this and figure out where exactly this is happening? I suspect it happens somewhere in a router redirect but I'm just not sure.

Here's said redirect

`<Route exact path='/login' render={() => authStore.isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to='/protected'/> : <Login/>}/>`

Ideas on how to debug this error?

Comment: your state depends on any external data? would be good to see more code too.

Comment: No. it doesn't depend on external data. I found the culprit in this case as well but I would still like to know if anyone has any methods for tracking down this sort of error because I run across it sometimes and I feel like there's a better way to debug than ripping out pieces one by one until i find the problem. Maybe a pattern / tool for tracking all re-renders and setStates? Does that make sense at all or am I living in a fantasy world?

Comment: you can use [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) extension for Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem by examining / expanding my consoles' stack trace,  narrowing it down to a specific component at which point the culprit was more obvious.

The problem was that I had a setState inside a promise that was being fired After my redirect happened (as shown in my original question). The `<Login/>` component was being removed from the DOM right before I was flipping a `fetching: true / false` state switch.

I feel like there's a better way to track setStates / re-renders for debugging. If anyone has a suggestion for a pattern / dev-tool (i'm aware of the react-dev-tools) that helps in these sort of issues please let me know!